# Emailing All Users In A Specific Role From Sitecore Workflow

Tags: workflow, sitecore

How can I send workflow notifications to all users in a Sitecore role? For instance, the next step in the workflow is for the Legal department to approve or reject. How can I make Sitecore send emails to all users in the Legal Approver role? I'm trying to avoid maintaining a distribution list and would like to grab users' email addresses dynamically.

Answer (score 9):

Sitecore security is based on ASP.NET security model. Hence, you can use standard ASP.NET API to obtain users of a certain role:

```cs
var users = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetUsersInRole("yourdomain\yourrole");
```

And later on iterate through the found users and read Email property:

```cs
foreach (var user in users)
{
  var membershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(user);
  var email = membershipUser.Email;
  // use this email to send the message to that user
}
```

I might be mistaken in syntax details, but I'm sure you can figure it out knowing the general idea.

Comment: These users are in Sitecore roles. How do I get the users in the Sitecore roles? I edited the question.

Comment: Hm, it seems I didn't clarify this and your question doesn't mention it explicitly -- what version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: I mean, the versions prior to 6.0 had own security system and related API. So, if you're using 5.X, the sample above won't work for you... Otherwise, it should work as is for Sitecore roles & users through standard ASP.NET security API

Comment: What about roles in roles? I haven't looked into this yet but how does Sitecore handle this within the normal membership provider?

Comment: Ah, roles in roles is a totally custom thing. It is build on top of ASP.NET security. Basically, it is just a SQL table storing the membership of roles in other roles, and a provider class to address this via API. You can explore RolesInRolesProvider in Reflector for more details.

Answer (score 4):

To resolve indirect membership you can use the `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.RolesInRolesManager` which also returns user accounts which are indirect part of the role specified.

```cs
RolesInRolesManager.GetUsersInRole(Role.FromName(roleName), true)
```